# Safe way to review a malicious JS file?

Tags: javascript

Recently someone sent me a eBay scam telling me to look at a screen shot, which lead to a javascript file download. I opened up the file in a text editor, I couldn't make sense of it but I am very curious as to what it is and what it does.

Is there a safe way I could poke around with the file in an isolated environment? I'm hesitant to post the file URL since I don't want to spread any sort of malware, but let me know if there is a safe way I can play around with something like this to find out what it does.

Comment: You could try [jsBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

Comment: You could set up a virtual machine on your computer, and then run it inside of that virtual machine to see what happens. But realistically you probably shouldn't run it because who knows what it will do. Do you just want to read it but it's all minified and jumbled?

Comment: @mmcrea It is actually formatted and cleanly written, but encrypted so all the functions are just jumbled letters. Am I allowed to share it or PM someone the script?

Comment: You could always copy/paste a snippet of the *jumbled* code into the Google machine and see if anybody has come across the same thing in the past. The quicker you can absolve yourself of this file, the better. Don't let your curiosity get the better of you, to the point you accidentally execute the file.